# Automatically provide HttpUnauthorizedResult (401 error) default StatusDescription instead of null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, http-error

In our ASP.NET MVC C# web application, we often want to return a generic Unauthorized message as a JSON response to AJAX calls if the user fails some kind of authentication check. My first thought was to do it this way:

```
return Json(new HttpUnauthorizedResult().StatusDescription);
```

The problem is, the `StatusDescription` property is `null` by default. It would be great if we could somehow overload the constructor to instantiate this property to have some generic unauthorized message if none is provided, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Does anyone know how to implement this? Please also feel free to suggest a better way to implement Http error messages in AJAX calls if this is not a good method.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpUnauthorizedResult` has a constructor that takes the description. You could use it [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpunauthorizedresult.httpunauthorizedresult(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.HttpUnauthorizedResult.)

```
return Json(new HttpUnauthorizedResult("token not found..."));
```

If the message is always the same you can inherits from HttpUnauthorizedResult:

```
public class MyHttpUnauthorizedResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult 
{
    public MyHttpUnauthorizedResult() : base("token not found") {}
}
```

Comment: I know I can provide it explicitly each time, but we'd like to not have to copy this message every time we want to use it. To have it automatically have a default value if none is provided is my goal.

Comment: You could define your own class that inherits from HttpUnauthorizedResult and provide the default message.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class that inherits from HttpUnauthorizedResult and chains to the base class constructor.

```
public class HttpUnauthorizedWithDefaultText : HttpUnauthorizedResult
{
    public HttpUnauthorizedWithDefaultText() : base("Some default text")
    {
    }
}
```

Then you could just do:

```
return Json(new HttpUnauthorizedResultWithDefaultText());
```